# Matlab ClassificationSVM class get weights w

Tags: matlab, svm

I am using ClassificationSVM class in MatLab for classification and I need to know a weight w given at each feature during the train with my dataset with ten features. The site for this class is mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm-class.html.

Is this weight the parameter Beta shown in the properties place? If not, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question needs more information. What is Beta? What formula are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put here a reference to the class I am using. Here is a link for that: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm-class.html. This class is a support vector machine classifier for one- or two-class learning. 
I need the weight for each feature to see if it is good or not for my discrimination process.
Beta is a property related with this kind of classifier shown in a table in the same site. My quastion is if I can get the weights I want with this Beta.

Comment: @jmfm Did you ever manage to figure out how to extract the weights for the optimal hyperplane, or `w`?  Judging from the documentation, `Beta` doesn't seem to be the weights `w`.

Answer (score 0):

(From the *Support Vector Machines for Binary Classification* subsection in the **Definitions** section on the same page: [ClassificationSVM](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm-class.html))

> The linear SVM score function is
>
> > f(x)=x′β+b

, followed by:

> The vector β contains the coefficients that define an orthogonal vector to the hyperplane (corresponding to Mdl.Beta)

So, according to this, the Beta parameter is indeed the weight vector.